# Ruby AWS SDK error. Value nil in module_inheritable_attributes.rb

Tags: ruby, aws-sdk

I have the following script:

```
require 'httparty'
require 'aws-sdk-s3'

include HTTParty

Aws.config.update({
  region: 'us-east-1',
  credentials: Aws::Credentials.new('...', '...')
})

client = Aws::S3::Resource.new
movies = self.class.get("#{HOST}/movies")
```

When I run it I'm met with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        10: from script.rb:33:in `<main>'
         9: from script.rb:33:in `new'
         8: from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/aws-sdk-athena-1.22.0/lib/aws-sdk-athena/resource.rb:14:in `initialize'
         7: from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.78.0/lib/seahorse/client/base.rb:99:in `new'
         6: from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/aws-sdk-athena-1.22.0/lib/aws-sdk-athena/client.rb:262:in `initialize'
         5: from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.78.0/lib/seahorse/client/base.rb:19:in `initialize'
         4: from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.78.0/lib/seahorse/client/base.rb:62:in `build_config'
         3: from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.78.0/lib/seahorse/client/configuration.rb:149:in `build!'
         2: from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.78.0/lib/seahorse/client/configuration.rb:158:in `empty_struct'
         1: from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.78.0/lib/seahorse/client/configuration.rb:158:in `new'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/httparty-0.17.1/lib/httparty/module_inheritable_attributes.rb:42:in `inherited': undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

After going through AWS's documentation and tutorials I still can't find the issue. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue to be the line `include HTTParty`. I declared the S3 client **before** that line and it works now:

```
require 'httparty'
require 'aws-sdk-s3'

Aws.config.update({
  region: 'us-east-1',
  credentials: Aws::Credentials.new('...', '...')
})
client = Aws::S3::Resource.new

include HTTParty

movies = self.class.get("#{HOST}/movies")
```